# Rails validates_uniqueness_of old data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've this validation in a model

`validates_uniqueness_of :name`

I created a new object with a default name and I save it without problems. After, I destroyed it and when I want to save a new object with the same name I have the following error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken`

I'm using Rails 3.0.20

```
2.1.5 :041 > f = FixtureType.new(:name => 'fixture type test')
 => #<FixtureType id: nil, name: "fixture type test", ...> 
2.1.5 :042 > f.save!
 => true 
2.1.5 :043 > f.destroy
 => #<FixtureType id: 1433, name: "fixture type test", ...> 
2.1.5 :044 > f = FixtureType.new(:name => 'fixture type test')
 => #<FixtureType id: nil, name: "fixture type test", ...> 
2.1.5 :045 > f.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using [`acts_as_paranoid`](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) or perhaps some other kind of archiving gem that hooks into the `destroy` method, thereby just "hiding" the object, rather than deleting it from your system?

Comment: I'm not using any gem, if I do a query with pgAdmin there isn't a row with the information of that object. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `name` actually a column of that table? Or is it a method referring to another table (from, e. g. `globalize`)? If it is an associated record, make sure that's cleaned up properly, accounting for `acts_as_paranoid` as Paul said above.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in the console you need to reload it to get the up to date results.

Try:

```
reload!
```

Or even logout or log back.

Cheers!